I want to copy an excel chart to a new sheet using VBA, and contain its data in itself, so that if i change the old sheets data, the chart stays
So i am making a statistical app in excel where users can fill their data into a sheet, that sheet automatically does the statistical analysis, and then has the statistical output (sometimes just values, but often also charts) in range AA:AT, then the macro should copy range AA:AT of that sheet, create a new sheet, and paste the values and charts on range A:T on the new sheet.
That all works fine, but the problem is, that when I automatically clear the first sheet (so a new analysis can be done), the chart of the new chart also loses its data.
I have tried to copy the range the chart uses with, and then somehow create a new data selection to that new range, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Either copy the data too (and make sure the chart refers to the copied data), or paste the chart as an image

Copy the entire sheet, then change its formulas to values.

Okay, this does work better already, but because there are a lot of formulas in the original sheet, it takes a long time to completely copy it, is there a way to speed it up?

Turn off calculation prior to the copy, turn back on once you've replaced the formulas with values. You may also want to turn screenupdating off

Yeah, already did, still takes ages

Perhaps you can create a dedicated sheet for the export, which only contains the bare minimum to get the output you need, using direct cell references where needed to the sources.
